# How to make custom brushes work in Illustator with automatisation

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, automation

I want to make a rectangle with a custom brush applied (so I load my custom brush library), and it works fine for the first image, but if I do that in automatisation, it does not load my brush for the next images, and there isn't an action for selecting by default my brush, so it just does empty rectangles for the rest. I tried to make it persistant, but in veins. Any idea? I work with Illustrator 2020.

Comment: Not enough info to fgure out what your problem may be. Relax and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your custom brushes are saved as a brush library. To do that, click the Menu icon in the Brushes panel and choose *Save brush library*. Make sure you save it in the default Brushes folder. Give it a name you can easily recognise.
2. In the Brushes panel click the Menu icon and choose *Open brush library*, click *User Defined* and the choose the brush library you just made.
3. When the Brush Library panel opens, click on the Menu icon, and select the *Persistent* option.

This will make sure the brushes are loaded and available when you start up Illustrator and create a new document or open an existing document, or want to record or use an Action that requires the brush to be loaded.

[image]